# PHP array -- recast as associative

Tags: php, arrays

I am having no success using `array_combine()`.  Can anyone help me get ...

### from THIS

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'traitvalue01' => string 'width'
          'traitvalue02' => string 'Length'
          'traitvalue03' => string 'Top'
          'traitvalue04' => string 'Bottom'
  1 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'trait01' => string '7 in'
          'trait02' => string '25 in'
          'trait03' => string '3 in'
          'trait04' => string '3 in'
```

### to THIS

```
array
    string 'width'  => string '7 in'
    string 'Length' => string '25 in'
    string 'Top'    => string '3 in'
    string 'Bottom' => string '3 in'
```

Comment: Perhaps if you would post what you tried, we might tell you what you're doing wrong. As it is, you're just asking for somebody to do your work for you.

Comment: I apologize if my presentation was inadequate.  I'm not at all lazy, but I couldn't understand the logic by myself.  Which contributes to my inability to explain the question well, of course.  Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
<?php

$a = array(
        array(
            array(
                'traitvalue01' => 'width',
                'traitvalue02' => 'Length',
                'traitvalue03' => 'Top',
                'traitvalue04' => 'Bottom'
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
              'trait01' => '7 in',
              'trait02' => '25 in',
              'trait03' => '3 in',
              'trait04' => '3 in'
            )
        )
    );

print_r(array_combine($a[0][0], $a[1][0]));

?>
```

And this is the output:

```
Array
(
    [width] => 7 in
    [Length] => 25 in
    [Top] => 3 in
    [Bottom] => 3 in
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
> $a = unset($yourArray[0][$key]); 
> $b = unset($yourArray[1][$key]);
> array_combine($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to double check - you could be passing the wrong arrays to array_combine().

Here's an example I threw together for you.  You can run it through your PHP binary to see the results (which are correct).

```
<?php
    $trait_array = array();
    array_push($trait_array, array(array('traitvalue01' => 'width', 'traitvalue02' => 'Length', 'traitvalue03' => 'Top', 'traitvalue04' => 'Bottom')));
    array_push($trait_array, array(array('trait01' => '7 in', 'trait02' => '25 in', 'trait03' => '3 in', 'trait04' => '3 in')));
    $result_array = array_combine($trait_array[0][0],$trait_array[1][0]);
    echo(print_r($result_array,1));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

are you try with array_combine?

```
$myarr = array(
              0=>array(
                  0=>array( 
                     'traitvalue01' => 'width',
                     'traitvalue02' => 'Length',
                     'traitvalue03' =>'Top',
                     'traitvalue04' => 'Bottom')),
             1=>array(
                  0=>array( 
                     'trait01' =>'7 in',
                     'trait02' => '25 in',
                     'trait03' => '3 in',
                     'trait04' => '3 in'))
          );
```

print_r(array_combine($myarr[0][0],$myarr[1][0]));

Result: 
Array
(
    [width] => 7 in
    [Length] => 25 in
    [Top] => 3 in
    [Bottom] => 3 in
)

And you make it dynamically. as you wish....simple.

Comment: Thank you Rajnish for what appears to be a correct answer.  I actually tried yours before Enzino's but somehow his presentation helped me better.  +upvote.